# Emacs crashing when opening ediff merge window with Magit

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-yosemite, magit

After a merge generating conflicts, I open the status window with

```
M-x magit-status
```

which displays, e.g.

```
Unstaged changes:
    Unmerged   .gitignore
```

(Also a pesky warning-window opens "Warning (el-get): Your Emacs doesn't support HTTPS (TLS).
Warning (:warning): for magit-1.4.0

You have just updated to version 1.4.0 of Magit, and have to
make a choice ..." I don't think this is the issue, but included it anyhow.)

When I move the cursor to .gitignore and type e to open the ediff merge tool, emacs entirely crashes.

The crash *seems* to happen when either I'm running neotree-mode or if I use ? to open a help buffer without neotree-mode.

The error report says

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[EmacsView(0x10d001760)     lockFocus] failed with window=0x1010e59c0, windowNumber=-1, [self    isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor]=0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
```

I'm running on OSX 10.10.5, GNU Emacs 24.5.1

Comment: Whatever you do in elisp shouldn't lead to a crash of Emacs. Folks on SO cannot do anything about a programming issue in Emacs either. So, I would suggest minimizing your .emacs setup to the minimum which allows for reproduction and then to use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: You should install v2 (currently v2.2.2). This issue might then go away, or not. But what you get for sure is a much nicer Magit. Maybe there was a bug in Magit or Ediff, but even if there was, then Emacs should still not crash - so there's also a bug in Emacs. Try to reproduce with Emacs' development version and consider reporting this issue. See https://debbugs.gnu.org/Emacs.html for instructions.